# How the initialization of a List may affect in my program?

Tags: arraylist, initialization, variable-assignment

Consider these two cases:

**a)**

```
List resultList = new ArrayList( );
resultList = getResultList( something );
```

**b)**

```
List resultList = null;
resultList = getResultList( something );
```

Is there any difference between "a" and "b"? 
Which should I use?

Answer (score 0):

A) initialize a List, so on you can use it normally in your code.

B) Makes it null, so if you want to use it in your code then you'll have to initialize it. ( "a)" option.)

Comment: thanks of your answer,and this make me edit my question again...how about the scenario a) and b)?any difference , purpose or impact between a) and b)?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand the question. Can you check it? What is "getResultList()" and what does the param "a" comes from.

Comment: If the  _"getResultList()"_ returns an non-null ArrayList, it shouldnt have any difference. Like this: 

`function getResultList(param){

     List myList = new ArrayList();
     myList.add(param); 
     return  myList;
}`

Otherwise, the **b** option will throw an error. Something like _NullReferenceException_.

Comment: i see,actually what i curious is,both of this is works,but what is the purpose they sometimes assign the resultList  to "new ArrayList( );" and sometimes,they just assign it to null?I just guess, is it "new ArrayList()" will cause any performance issues?maybe make the apps slower?

Comment: If you are not going to use it in the moment it will, but it is really really small the improvement if you assign it to null. Anyway, is depending on the language you're using and how the variables are saved in memory. There is no significant difference unless you need to micro-improve.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question. In the first case, you have only declared the list. You'll still have to initialize the list in your code before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

As the result they are same.

But (a) has an unnecessary operation `new ArrayList`, because it creates `ArrayList` and then discard it at once.

BTW: For the readability the best way should be:

```
List resultList = getResultList( param );
```